# Where does the `Runnable` get executed?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am trying to wrap my head around the concepts of `Thread`, `Looper` and `Handler` architecture in Android. So as of my understanding at the moment, we can associate a thread with a looper and handler. Looper has a messagequeue in which it stores messages and runnable which are then handled by the loop ( I read it from this [site](http://codetheory.in/android-handlers-runnables-loopers-messagequeue-handlerthread/) (Looper and MessageQueue section) that it contains runnable also) . So I wanted to know how it handles the runnable in the queues by checking the source code for the `loop` function in
`Looper` class ([link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Looper.java) for that). Now when I see the `loop` function code which I am pasting here for reference

```
public static void loop() {
    final Looper me = myLooper();
    if (me == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No Looper; Looper.prepare() wasn't called on this thread.");
    }
    final MessageQueue queue = me.mQueue;

    // Make sure the identity of this thread is that of the local process,
    // and keep track of what that identity token actually is.
    Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
    final long ident = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();

    for (;;) {
        Message msg = queue.next(); // might block
        if (msg == null) {
            // No message indicates that the message queue is quitting.
            return;
        }

        // This must be in a local variable, in case a UI event sets the logger
        Printer logging = me.mLogging;
        if (logging != null) {
            logging.println(">>>>> Dispatching to " + msg.target + " " +
                    msg.callback + ": " + msg.what);
        }

        msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);

        if (logging != null) {
            logging.println("<<<<< Finished to " + msg.target + " " + msg.callback);
        }

        // Make sure that during the course of dispatching the
        // identity of the thread wasn't corrupted.
        final long newIdent = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
        if (ident != newIdent) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Thread identity changed from 0x"
                    + Long.toHexString(ident) + " to 0x"
                    + Long.toHexString(newIdent) + " while dispatching to "
                    + msg.target.getClass().getName() + " "
                    + msg.callback + " what=" + msg.what);
        }

        msg.recycleUnchecked();
    }
}
```

I am unable to find where it processes the runnables in the messagequeue. Seeing the code it seems like only message objects are processed there.

So in gist my question is "Where and when the looper processes the runnable items in the message queue? And if it doesn't itself process where does it pass them?". I am very new to Android, sorry if my question seems stupid. I am trying to understand the concepts of Handler Loopers since past two days, but I am kind of stuck. I tried to search a lot about my specific question, but it links me back to original link from where I was reading ?

Comment: in  `handleCallback(msg);` http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Handler.java#95

Comment: could you be a bit more specific ? Reading the handler code also there is no method like `process` there are methods like `post` which post to the messagequeue .

Comment: see `handleCallback` method, http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Handler.java#handleCallback, its body is: `message.callback.run();` this is where your `Runnable` is run

Comment: @pskink okay if I understand it right, that means the looper passes the messages/runnables to the handler and it is the handler which handles them appropriately depending on whether it is a message or runnable. Am I right ?

Comment: i couldn't describe it better

Comment: thanks a lot for being patient :) ! I understand it now